# Does rule of not embedding std::string in exceptions still hold with move constructors?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, move-constructor

I heard some time ago that I should not create exception classes which would have fields of `std::string` type. That's what [Boost website says](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html). The rationale is that `std::string` copy constructor can throw an exception if memory allocation fails, and if an exception is thrown before the currently processed exception is caught, the program is terminated.

However, does it still hold in the world of move constructors? Won't the move constructor be used instead of the copy constructor when throwing an exception? Do I understand correctly that with C++11 no memory allocation will take place, no chance of exception exists and `std::string` is absolutely fine in exception classes now?

Comment: The [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (overload #8) is indeed `noexcept`, so that part seems plausible. I don't know where to confirm that throwing indeed moves though, nor whether this is the only reason against `std::string` in exceptions.

Comment: If your program is so critical it must operate with zero available heap memory, perhaps you should consider rewriting it with tight memory requirements in mind, perhaps in a different language, or with a different library. Otherwise, let it terminate, it's useless at this point anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

Yes, you still don't want to embed a `std::string` into your exception types.  Exceptions are often copied, sometimes without your knowledge. For example, on some platforms `std::rethrow_exception` will copy the exception (and on some it won't).

For best practice, keep your copy constructor `noexcept`.

However all is not lost.  A little known fact is that C++ has always had within the standard an immutable ref-counted string type (with a non-throwing copy constructor), just with an obfuscated name.  Two names actually:

```
logic_error
runtime_error
```

The specs for these types are such that they must contain an immutable ref-counted string-like object.  Well, not completely immutable.  You can replace the string with an assignment.  But you can't otherwise modify the string in place.

My advice is to either derive from one of these types, or if that is not acceptable, embed one of these types and treat it as an immutable ref-counted string type:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class error1
    : public std::runtime_error
{
    using msg_ = std::runtime_error;
public:
    explicit error1(std::string const& msg)
        : msg_(msg)
    {}
};

class error2
{
    std::runtime_error msg_;
public:
    explicit error2(std::string const& msg)
        : msg_(msg)
    {}

    char const* what() const noexcept {return msg_.what();}
};

void
test_error1()
{
    try
    {
        throw error1("test1");
    }
    catch (error1 const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}

void
test_error2()
{
    try
    {
        throw error2("test2");
    }
    catch (error2 const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}

int
main()
{
    test_error1();
    test_error2();
}
```

The std::lib will take care of all the string-handling and memory management for you, and you get `noexcept` copying in the bargain:

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<error1>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable   <error1>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<error2>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable   <error2>{}, "");
```

Comment: Clang SVN with `-std=c++1z` allows to drop those pesky quotes in `static_assert`

Answer (score 1):

Whether a copy of the `string` is made when an exception is thrown depends on the `catch` block.

Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
};

void foo()
{
   throw A();
}

void test1()
{
   try
   {
      foo();
   }
   catch (A&& a)
   {
   }
}

void test2()
{
   try
   {
      foo();
   }
   catch (A const& a)
   {
   }
}

void test3()
{
   try
   {
      foo();
   }
   catch (A a)
   {
   }
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
   test3();
}
```

You will not make a copy of `A` in `test1` or `test2` but you will end up making a copy in `test3`.

Comment: I guess it will be still move in `test3` as `A()` is an rvalue. if it was `A a; throw a;` inside `foo`, it would have been copy in `test3`

Comment: § 15.1/3 "Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object."
§ 15.1/5 "When the thrown object is a class object, the constructor selected for the copy-initialization and the destructor shall be accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided".  Ergo, the `throw` also induces a copy/move, though it's probably elided.